# VBA script why not runnable via command line

Tags: vba

I need to run this script outside excel, via powershell/command line.
But I don't know why in excel works propertly as a macro and outside as .vbs via command line a lot of errors happens.
How can I convert it or use this script via command line?
Thanks

```
Sub csvToXLS(SourcePath, SheetOutput)
    Sheets.Add.Name = SheetOutput
    Sheets(SheetOutput).Select

'    Open SourcePath For Input As #1
    Open "C:\temp\Estrattore\2022_07_01-Report123.csv" For Input As #1
    row_number = 0
    
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, LineFromFile
        LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ";")
        ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 0).Value = LineItems(0)       ' Il nostro CSV prevede 7 campi (da 0 a 6)
        ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 1).Value = LineItems(1)
        ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 2).Value = LineItems(2)
        ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 3).Value = LineItems(3)
        ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 4).Value = LineItems(4)
        ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 5).Value = LineItems(5)
        ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 6).Value = LineItems(6)
        row_number = row_number + 1
    Loop
    Close #1
    
    Sheets(SheetOutput).Rows(1).AutoFilter                          ' Imposto il filtro automatico
    Sheets(SheetOutput).Rows(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 31            ' Coloro la prima riga
    Worksheets(SheetOutput).Columns("A:I").AutoFit                  ' Imposto l'autofit, ovvero la colonna ha dimensione tale da mostrare ogni risultato
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False                                ' first, ensure that no panes are frozen
    Rows("2:2").Select                                              ' select the row that you want to freeze based on
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True                                 ' freeze panes


End Sub

Sub main()
    Call csvToXLS("C:\temp\Estrattore\2022_07_01-Report1.csv", "Report1")
    Call csvToXLS("C:\temp\Estrattore\2022_07_01-Report2.csv", "Report2")
    Call csvToXLS("C:\temp\Estrattore\2022_07_01-Report3.csv", "Report3")
    Call csvToXLS("C:\temp\Estrattore\2022_07_01-Report123.csv", "Report123")
End Sub
```

Comment: You copied this entire code into a VBS file and tried to run it?

Comment: VBS and VBA are not exactly the same thing.  For example, how would your code know what `Sheets` is if it's not running in Excel at the time?

Comment: well, right off the bat, you try to call `Sheets.Add` which in the context of running in excel would work because there is a kind of implicit `ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add` that executes. In the context of a VB script running from powershell, it would have no idea what `Sheets.Add` means because `Sheets` is not a thing. and no Excel instance is even referenced.